# Cannot GET /tvshow

Tags: node.js, rest, express

im working with Node.js to create API Rest simple, the server run without error and connect succefull with database, but when I call the rest api, this don't response any.

I other questions I see the people forget set a route, but in this code I set all routes and call the data.

App.js:

```
var express         = require("express"),
    app             = express(),
    bodyParser      = require("body-parser"),
    methodOverride  = require("method-override"),
    mongoose        = require('mongoose');

// Connection to DB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/tvshows', function(err, res) {
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log('Connected to Database');
});

// Middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());

// Import Models and controllers
var models     = require('./models/tvshow')(app, mongoose);
var TVShowCtrl = require('./controllers/tvshows');


var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send("Hello world!");
});
app.use(router);

// API routes
var tvshows = express.Router();

tvshows.route('/tvshows')
  .get(TVShowCtrl.findAllTVShows)
  .post(TVShowCtrl.addTVShow);

tvshows.route('/tvshows/:id')
  .get(TVShowCtrl.findById)
  .put(TVShowCtrl.updateTVShow)
  .delete(TVShowCtrl.deleteTVShow);

app.use('/api', tvshows);

// Start server
app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Node server running on http://localhost:3000");
});
```

controllers/tvshows.js:

```
//File: controllers/tvshows.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var TVShow  = mongoose.model('TVShow');

//GET - Return all tvshows in the DB
exports.findAllTVShows = function(req, res) {
    TVShow.find(function(err, tvshows) {
    if(err) res.send(500, err.message);

    console.log('GET /tvshows')
        res.status(200).jsonp(tvshows);
    });
};

//GET - Return a TVShow with specified ID
exports.findById = function(req, res) {
    TVShow.findById(req.params.id, function(err, tvshow) {
    if(err) return res.send(500, err.message);

    console.log('GET /tvshow/' + req.params.id);
        res.status(200).jsonp(tvshow);
    });
};

//POST - Insert a new TVShow in the DB
exports.addTVShow = function(req, res) {
    console.log('POST');
    console.log(req.body);

    var tvshow = new TVShow({
        title:    req.body.title,
        year:     req.body.year,
        country:  req.body.country,
        poster:   req.body.poster,
        seasons:  req.body.seasons,
        genre:    req.body.genre,
        summary:  req.body.summary
    });

    tvshow.save(function(err, tvshow) {
        if(err) return res.send(500, err.message);
    res.status(200).jsonp(tvshow);
    });
};

//PUT - Update a register already exists
exports.updateTVShow = function(req, res) {
    TVShow.findById(req.params.id, function(err, tvshow) {
        tvshow.title   = req.body.petId;
        tvshow.year    = req.body.year;
        tvshow.country = req.body.country;
        tvshow.poster  = req.body.poster;
        tvshow.seasons = req.body.seasons;
        tvshow.genre   = req.body.genre;
        tvshow.summary = req.body.summary;

        tvshow.save(function(err) {
            if(err) return res.send(500, err.message);
      res.status(200).jsonp(tvshow);
        });
    });
};

//DELETE - Delete a TVShow with specified ID
exports.deleteTVShow = function(req, res) {
    TVShow.findById(req.params.id, function(err, tvshow) {
        tvshow.remove(function(err) {
            if(err) return res.send(500, err.message);
      res.status(200);
        })
    });
};
```

In similar questions, all forget set a route, but in this code y send route

> app.use('/api', tvshows);

And then I try to call REST:

> Error
>
> ```
> Cannot POST /tvshow
> ```

But I don't understand the reason, what I doing wrong?

Comment: can you post your client request as well? what url are you using?

Comment: Lol, I forget add 'api', I called http://localhost:3000/tvshows

Comment: when you do this, `app.use('/api', tvshows);`, you are mapping the `tvshows` router after `/api`, so your `/tvshows` route is available in `localhost:3000/api/tvshows`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the `tvshows` routes with the `/api` prefix here:

```
app.use('/api', tvshows);
```

So you should call `/api/tvshows`

Or if you want to use directly `/tvshows`, use the router like this:

```
app.use('/', tvshows);
```

See the [use examples on the documentation](http://expressjs.com/fr/4x/api.html#path-examples).

Answer (score 0):

There's no route to `/tvshow`, only `/tvshows`